# how can I run my functions be sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

```
function Getir() {
    var options =
    {
        host: 'example',
        port: 443,
        path: '/myUrl'
    };

    get(options, function (http_res) {
        var data = "";


        http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {

            data += chunk;
        });

        
        http_res.on("end", function () {
            
            writeFile('NewHtml.txt', `${data}`, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
        });
    });
}


function DegistirDuzenle() {
    if (existsSync("./DatabaseHtml.txt")) {

        var DataBaseHtml = readFileSync("./DatabaseHtml.txt", 'utf-8', (err) => { if (err) console.log(err) });
        var MyHtml = readFileSync("./NewHtml.txt", 'utf-8', (err) => {if (err) console.log(err) });

        if (MyHtml == DataBaseHtml) {
            unlink("./NewHtml.txt", (err)=>{ if(err) console.log(err)});
            console.log("değişiklik yapılmadı");
        } else {
            //notification

            console.log("değişiklik yapıldı");

            //Change
            unlink('./DatabaseHtml.txt', (err) => { if(err) console.log(err); });
            writeFile('./DatabaseHtml.txt', `${MyHtml}`, 'utf-8', (err) => { if(err) console.log(err); });
            unlink('./NewHtml.txt', (err) => { if(err) console.log(err); });
        }

    }
    else {
        writeFile('DatabaseHtml.txt', `NewDataBaseHtml`, 'utf8', (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    }
}

async function Mysystem() {
    let mypromis = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        resolve(Getir());
    });
    await mypromis.then(DegistirDuzenle());
}
Mysystem();
```

I want to create a txt file, read it and delete it later. I have 2 function 1.(Getir()) Create txt, 2.(DegistirDuzenle()) read txt and delete but 2. function starts working first and I getting error. "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './NewHtml.txt'"

Comment: Is your Getir function async ?

Comment: any chance of more context, what the errors actually are, or maybe a sandbox link? Check out the [How do I ask a good question? post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to better structure a question. It's beneficial for everyone.

Comment: You are using both ways to handle promises. Can you give us tell us if Getir and DegistirDuzenle are also async functions ?

Comment: Please also post the code of `Getir` and `DegistirDuzenle`. You can [edit] your question to include them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function Mysystem() {
    let mypromis = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        resolve(Getir());
    });
    await mypromis()
    await DegistirDuzenle()
}

Mysystem()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
async function Mysystem() {
    await Getir();
    await DegistirDuzenle();
}
```

or

```
function Mysystem() {
    return Getir().then(DegistirDuzenle);
}
```

but not a mix of them. Also notice that when passing the `DegistirDuzenle` function to `.then()` as a callback, it shouldn't be invoked (passing the result of a call, not passing the function). Alternatively, you could write `.then((getirResult) => DegistirDuzenle())`.

---

Also, for this to work, you'll need to properly [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the code in `Getir` and `DegistirDuzenle`.

Comment: both didn't work I guess because my functions are not asynchronous

Comment: Yes indeed.  `Getir()` needs to return a promise that fulfills when the file is downloaded.

Comment: my promise  stays in the```Promise { <pending> }``` state for ```console.log(await getir())```. how to make my function turn promise

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572